# The science of energy manipulation powers

Tags: science-based, energy, super-powers

Trying to create a hero with energy manipulating powers but I know nothing about energy and Captain Atom and Doctor Solar seem pretty accurate with showing versatility with using this sort of power. How do I learn about it?

Comment: These fictional characters your so called superheroes are granted a one time correction unlimited times of scientific miracle before they are licensed to kick some ass, energy can come in many forms but it cannot be created nor destroyed so bear this in mind now grant s/he any power you can dream of and do some work lol.

Comment: Agreed. Where and what should I be researching? I want to narrate scientifically accurate story lines about how my character can absorb so much energy they can, teleport, have access to other realities, fly,project different forms of energy and the outcome of using these energies and what they can effect with these energies. And how they can control their atomic structure and transmute matter.

Comment: This is not just duplicate, it's an exact plagiarised copy of another duplicate of the dupe target.

Comment: . . . Why would you re-ask this?

Comment: Duplicating what?

Answer (score 0):

Taking note of the [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) tag:

**Energy** is a concerved quantity formally defined as that which comes out of Noether's Theorm due to the symmetry of time.

To learn about energy, look at the subject of *physics*.  I'll share a favorite link with you: a series of TV shows from PBS called [The Mechanical Universe](http://www.learner.org/resources/series42.html). After a couple episodes you'll know enough to ask intelligent specific questions. But come episodes 13 through 15 you'll cover this topic directly.

---

*energy* can cause things to move, or be stored in some manner and such storage of "form of energy" is caused by matter's interaction with it. Thus those same forms can be controlled or shaped by matter as well.

There are many forms like batteries, chemical bonds, springs, heavy objects on high shelves.

So I think your question is as vague and open as is possible: anything the hero *does* to the bad guy is manipulating energy.  A punch is good old kenetic energy, and he uses chemical energy in his body to emit it.

If he squirts acid to imjur the opponent, that is chemical energy being released as it reacts with the opponent's tissue.

Comment: Is that its definition? But what about if we had a world where energy was able to be created or destroyed at some point? Without conservation of energy, there is no time-symmetry, but "energy" could still be a viable concept even in a world like this, right?

Comment: In this physics question, they seem to treat the time-symmtry/conservation of energy as a fact about energy rather than a definition of it. So I don't think you're correct in presenting this as the definition of energy. I don't know enough physics to explain how energy is actually defined, but I think it's a bit more involved. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108088/why-is-energy-conserved

Comment: As a deep concept, *energy* comes from having rules that allow things to change over time, and having a concept of time.  You can't not conserve it unless the rules themself change over time. You always find a bookkeeping method to explain it, such as *dark energy* always increasing is borrowing against the account of gravitational potential energy which has no credit limit.

Comment: As for being the best end-all definition, you can keep finding more forms of energy as more stuff is discovered, and list them all and somehow recognising the essential features of new ones. Invoking "a concervative force" as a criteria to recognize is exactly using Noether's Theorm as the defining quantity.  Now every informal explaination of the *action principle* formulation of physical law is circular as it mentions potential energy. So how you bootstrap the formal definitions will determine whether the concept is an input (given or axiom) or output (theorem).

Comment: The top answer on that Physics SE post doesn't say how it's defined in lowest terms, only that the Hamiltonian is equivalent to total energy which is the same as the "charge" in a scalar field where Noether's Theorm applies.

Comment: http://www.comicvine.com/captain-atom/4005-2050/forums/new-52-captain-atom-respect-thread-688013/                                                                       How are comics able to explain this? All I want to know for all of these capabilities he can do is why?

Comment: Sonar has absolute control of energy; consequently, resulting in him being able to accomplish outlandish feats, which primarily consist of reality warping/manipulation, such as: time traveling, flying, blasting bolts of energy, control of gravity, (de)construction of realities, creation of universes/multi-verses, reviving the dead, erasing people from existence, etc.

Comment: The previous comment on Sonar states he can do all those. How are comics able to create these associated with energy manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Since energy can't be created or destroyed, you're going to have to borrow it from somewhere else.

Pretty much all super powers are just this side of magic (and a lot are way over the line), but I'll attempt for science-based... or try at least.

**Heat energy**
Take a volume of matter (air, water, whatever), and borrow a little heat energy from each molecule. Focus that into a small area, and you have some intense heat. Geo thermal furnaces work on this principle.

**Electricity**
There are electrons all around us. Steal electrons by ionizing the air into a plasma toward the target, and then release those electrons as [lightening](http://www.zdnet.com/article/new-military-weapon-shoots-lightning-bolts/).

Neither of these are scientifically possible for a person to do without equipment. Just some ideas.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/respectthreads/comments/2fpjiq/respect_the_silver_surfer/